# Problems accessing private data members c++

Tags: c++

I have three files: Stack.cc, Stack.h and stacktest.cc . I am not sure about which files to include where, and i am getting different errors because of it. Currently, the code from Stack.h is:

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Stack
{
public:
    Stack();
    void push(int);
    void pop();
    int top();
    int size();
    bool empty();   

private:
    class Element
    {
    public:
        int data;
        Element *next;
        Element(Element *n, T d) : next{n}, data{d} {}
    };
    Element *first;
    int num;
};
#endif
#include"Stack.cc"
```

the (relevant, i think) code from Stack.cc is:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
template<typename T>
Stack<T>::Stack()
{
    first=nullptr;
}


template<typename T>
void Stack<T>::push(int)
{
    num++;
    first = new Element(first, data);
}
```

Stacktest is currently just a test file attempting to call the default constructor. The errors i currently get are:

```
In file included from Stack.h:30:0,
             from stacktest.cc:2:
Stack.cc: In member function ‘void Stack<T>::push(int)’:
Stack.cc:22:28: error: ‘data’ was not declared in this scope
 first = new Element(first, data);
                        ^
Stack.cc: In function ‘int size()’:
Stack.cc:62:11: error: ‘num’ was not declared in this scope
return num;
```

For some reason it wont let me access private data members. Before i didnt have the include in the .h file and instead included the .h in Stack.cc, and that worked, although wouldnt let me access the stack class from Stacktest.cc(Stacktest.cc just includes Stack.h)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: did you mean `push(int data)` instead of `push(int)` ?

Comment: also I guess you wrote `int size() {` in Stack.cc when you meant `int Stack<T>::size() {`

Comment: typically, you include- .h file in .cc file and not the other way (in your example you include .cc file in .h). in the stacktest.cc, you'd include stack.h file

Comment: There are *many* things wrong with this code, but primarily it is just too complicated. The errors you see have nothing to do with templates or the `#include` directive, which means that you can reduce this to a simpler example-- and you should have noticed the errors before writing so much code. If you *simplify*, you'll see that the error messages mean just what they say; you're trying to use two variables outside their scope (that is, where they don't exist).

Comment: you can start by removing using namespace std from your header.

Comment: Your Stack doesn't know 'data', because it is a part of the sub class Element. give the int parameter a name and pass that to the creation of the Element.

Comment: Apologies, i am still slightly confused. I fixed the errors everyone said, included the .h in the .cc, but now when i compile my stacktest file cannot access anything from Stack, i get "undefined reference to 'Stack<int>::Stack()' or whichever function i choose to use. What am i missing?